# There is always a vm running on vagrant and I can't destroy it

Tags: vagrant

look the picture below for what i did
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k58hH.png)

I need help

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to run

```
vagrant global-status --prune
```

It will clean the list from global-status and remove the VM if it does not exist